# Featured Image If Else Condition

Tags: customization, pages, post-thumbnails, images

I have my banner background set to the URL of the featured image.

```
<div id='xpro_shell_text' >
  <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
  <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
  <div id="xpro_shell_content_header"  class='content_about_us_header white' style="background:url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>') no-repeat;">
    <div id='xpro_shell_content_header_blurb'>
      <h1 class='greenHeader cufon_reg'>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h1>
      <p>
        <?php $message=get_post_meta($post->ID, "myBlurb", true);
 if (get_post_meta($post->ID, "myBlurb", true)) {
 echo ($message);
 } ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <!--end xpro_shell_content_wrapper_top --> 
</div>
```

I want a default banner background set if i didn't put a Featured image. 
How can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
<div id='xpro_shell_text' >
  <?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) :
        $imageInfo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
        $imageUrl = $imageInfo[0];
    else:
        $imageUrl = get_template_directory() . 'PATH TO YOUR DEFAULT IMAGE';
    endif;
  ?>
  <div id="xpro_shell_content_header"  class='content_about_us_header white' style="background:url('<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>') no-repeat;">
    <div id='xpro_shell_content_header_blurb'>
      <h1 class='greenHeader cufon_reg'>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h1>
      <p>
        <?php 
             $message=get_post_meta($post->ID, "myBlurb", true);
             if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, "myBlurb", true) ) {
                echo ($message);
             } 
        ?>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--end xpro_shell_content_wrapper_top --> 
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

The trick is here:

```
// If we have a featured image, it will be used as background image using the same logic you already used, but we put the src value in a specific variable: $imageUrl
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) :
  $imageInfo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
  $imageUrl = $imageInfo[0];
// if not, we define $imageUrl with our default image src value
else:
  $imageUrl = get_template_directory() . 'PATH TO YOUR DEFAULT IMAGE';
endif;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: please give more explanation

Comment: @JMau sorry, for the inconvenience but i've pasted over a previously answer from my text editor, overwriting my explanation

Comment: @JMau, no problem : )

Comment: @JeremiLiwanag, you're welcome